# Is this function in the space $L^1$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have this function
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\vert x-y\vert^2(1+\vert x\vert^2)^s}$$
with $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $y$ a fixed point. I have to study for which values of $s>0$ it belongs to $L^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$.
If I choose $y=0$ I have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{\vert x\vert^2(1+\vert x\vert^2)^s}dx=4\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+r^2)^s}<\infty$$
if and only if $s>\frac{1}{2}$. For $y\neq 0$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{\vert x-y\vert^2(1+\vert x\vert^2)^s}dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{1}{\vert t\vert^2(1+\vert t+y\vert^2)^s}dx$$
How can I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the change of variable $x=y+z$ and $c_y\cdot(1+|z|^2)\leqslant1+|y+z|^2\leqslant C_y\cdot(1+|z|^2)$ for some positive and finite $c_y$ and $C_y$. This reduces the general case to the case $y=0$, which you solved.

To see that such constants $c_y$ and $C_y$ exist, note for example that $|y+z|\leqslant|y|+|z|$ hence $|y+z|^2\leqslant2|y|^2+2|z|^2$ hence $1+|y+z|^2\leqslant2(1+|y|^2)(1+|z|^2)$ and $C_y=2(1+|y|^2)$ is valid.

You may want to deduce from the above that $c_y=1/C_y$ is valid as well, thus completing the proof.